# In JavaScript Google Flatbuffers, how does one write a ulong?

Tags: javascript, flatbuffers

I have no problem with doing this in a C++ program, but I am stuck on writing a ulong in JS.

FB has no issue if I used the 32bit process.hrtime() value.

But how does do a createLong() for a 64bit ?

see: [ https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_bigint ]

```
# commented line does not work
# let timeStamp = process.hrtime.bigint()
        let timeStamp = process.hrtime()
        let ts = builder.createLong(0, timeStamp)
        PNT.Telemetry.startTelemetry(builder)
        PNT.Telemetry.addSystemTime(builder, ts)
```

---

### FB template file

```
// Simple Telemetry data from/to Sim and Sensor
namespace PNT;
enum DeviceType:byte { IMU, VAN, GPS, MAGNAV, SOOP }
struct PosVector {
  lat:double;
  lon:double;
  alt:double;
}
table Telemetry {
  source: string;
  systemTime:ulong = 0;
  systemTimeString: string;
  description: string;
  position: PosVector; 
}

root_type Telemetry;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function, it works well for timestamp

```
var flatBufferTimeStamp = function(value) {
    var bin = (value).toString(2); 
    var pad = new Array(64 - bin.length + 1 ).join('0'); 
    bin = pad + bin;  
    return {
        low: parseInt(bin.substring(32), 2), 
        high: parseInt(bin.substring(0, 32), 2)
    };
}


var timeStamp = flatBufferTimeStamp(process.hrtime())
let ts = builder.createLong(timeStamp.low, timeStamp.high);
PNT.Telemetry.startTelemetry(builder)
PNT.Telemetry.addSystemTime(builder, ts)
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flatbuffers/ieXNEsB_2wc

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatbuffers.Long`, here is an example: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/tests/JavaScriptTest.js#L160

Sadly there is no code in FlatBuffers to convert a bigint to the 2 32-bit values, which would be good to add. For now you may need to do your own conversion.

Comment: All the bitewise operators I see at mdn say they are for 32bit.

Comment: I will add the klutz question, since I have not done much bigint() bit twiddling in javascript (my experience was 35+ years ago in C for this). What is a good efficient way to break the bigint into two 32 bit unsigned?

Comment: Not that familiar with JS either, sorry.